# How to upgrade your project for ios 3.0 to ios 6.0 onwords

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Right now I am working on non-arc project for ios3.0. They haven't designed anything by interface builder. Everything coded is both for landscape view and portrait view separately. My Problem is when I try to add the same image for background of another screen, it appears to be cropped. also enabling the auto resize subviews gives me error. When I try to set views for portrait and landscape view, it doesn't work.

one more thing, that project is only developed for iPad. if they want it to be done for iPhones, should i have to start from scratch separately for iPhone because of above mentioned problems ?

please suggest me if the upgraded app will support for 64 bit ipad retina.

Thanx in advance

Comment: If you want it in iPhone then you will have to create a new project. One if it is created for iPad then it cannot be changed.

Comment: When creating a new project select Universal if you want to use the app both in iPad and iPhone.

Comment: Have you tried to change the parameters in `General` tab of `Target` field

Comment: Create New Universal app with UIStoryBoard + AutoLayout.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi I tried this earlier but doesn't work for iPhone's view

Answer (score 1):

Make your project universal by changing the setting shown in the image below. Also it is better to drop support for iOS 3 as nobody uses it anymore and support iOS 6 and above. It will give much more options and flexibility regarding frameworks and layouts.

To support 64-bit devices you have to build with iOS 5 or higher as minimum supported iOS version. Best practice is to support the two latest releases (iOS 6 and 7 at this moment) as most iOS users update their devices fast after each os release.

[image]

Comment: I tried to set this option. But doesn't work to give apropriate view for iPhone